Conditional color formatting using handlebars and html inside PowerApps
I'm making an app with PoweApps, using Scott Durow's PFC Power Drag and Drop.
This PCF gets data from a collection and display the items to be dragged according to a template that uses HTML and Handlebars.
I'm new to HTML and to Handlebars, so I'm struggling to make a conditional formatting. I want the left border color of a div to change according to one of the fields I'm retrieving from the collection and displaying in the items.
My code so far is:
<! –– This for the whole card ––>
<div class=""card"" style=""
    display: block;
    min-height:40px;
    max-height:80px;
    background-color: transparent; 
    border: 1px ;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-left: 3px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
    margin: 5px;
    align-items: center;
"">
    <! –– This for the whole container in the card ––>
    <div class=""container"" style=""
        background-color: transparent;
        padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
        align-items: center
        ;
    "">
    <! –– This is the first line, divided in two parts ––>
    <div class=""flex-container"" style=""
        display: flex;
         padding: 0 0 0 0px;
         background-color: transparent;
         align-items: center;
    "">
            <! –– First line part 1 = LOTE ––>
            <div class=""flex-child"" style=""
                    flex: 3;
                    margin: 0px;
                    background-color: transparent;
                    align-items: center;
                    font-size:110%;
                "">    <b>{{cr870_lote}} </b>
                </div>
            <! –– First line part 2 = MODS ––>
            <div class=""flex-child"" style=""
                flex: 3;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: transparent;
                color:red;
            "">   <b>{{cr870_mods}}</b>
            </div>
    </div>
    <! –– Second line of my container, also divided in two parts ––>
    <div class=""flex-container"" style=""
        display: flex;
        padding: 0 0 0 0px;
        background-color: transparent;
        align-items: center;
    "">
                
                <! –– Second line part 1 = Pedido and purification ––>
                <div class=""flex-child"" style=""
                    flex: 5;
                    margin: 0px;
                    background-color: transparent;
                    align-items: center;
                ""> {{cr870_pedido}}  | {{cr870_purification}}
                </div>

                <! –– Second line part 2 = Nucleotides ––>
                <div class=""flex-child"" style=""
                    flex: 1;
                    text-align: right;
                    background-color: transparent;
                "">   {{cr870_nt}}nt
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

This code gives me the following:

What I would like to do is to change this red left border color so that it is Yellow if my {{cr870_purification}} is "Dessal", blue if it is "Cartridge" and purple if it is "HPLC".
I've already tried:
<div class=""card"" style=""
    display: block;
    min-height:40px;
    max-height:80px;
    background-color: transparent; 
    border: 1px ;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-left:  

    {{#if (eq cr870_purification 'Dessal')}} 3px solid yellow
    {{else if (eq cr870_purification 'Cartridge')}} 3px solid blue
    {{else}} 3px solid red
    {{/if}};

    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
    margin: 5px;
    align-items: center;
"">

Didn't work. I don't even know if it didn't work because it is not the right way to do it or if I wrote the wrong syntax, since I'm new to these languages and, to make it  worse, my powerapps is in BR portuguese regional language.
Any tips?
